# Issue with MUnit and Spring Security Schema

Tags: spring-security, mule, munit

I have a API-kit project that incorporates spring security basic authentication. The application builds and runs successfully without MUnit tests. When including MUnit tests, it fails to build giving the following:

```
WARN  2019-07-09 11:21:18,619 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/current/mule-spring-security.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Running the MUnit tests themselves, all pass.

The flows that implement this security use the following:

```
<mule-ss:http-security-filter
            doc:name="API Secutiry filter"
            realm="mule-realm"
            securityProviders="delegateSecurityProvider" />
```

where the security manager is defined as:

```
<mule-ss:security-manager
    name="Spring_Security_Provider"
    doc:name="Spring Security Provider">
    <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider
        name="delegateSecurityProvider"
        delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
</mule-ss:security-manager>
```

and the authentication manager is defined as:

```
<spring:beans>
    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <ss:authentication-provider>
            <ss:user-service id="userService">
                <ss:user
                    name="${gov.mt.dphhs.telcor.authentication.user}"
                    password="${gov.mt.dphhs.telcor.authentication.password}"
                    authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </ss:user-service>
        </ss:authentication-provider>
    </ss:authentication-manager>
</spring:beans>
```

The XML namespaces are as follows:

```
xmlns:mule-ss="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security"
xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/current/mule-spring-security.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
```

Additional information:

```
<mule.version>3.8.0</mule.version>
<mule.tools.version>1.2</mule.tools.version>
<munit.version>1.3.7</munit.version>
```

Comment: maybe the mule.version is wrong? http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/spring-security/3.8/ try with 3.8 only

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are missing the spring-security module

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
  <artifactId>mule-module-spring-security</artifactId>
  <version>${mule.version}</version>
</dependency>
```